# keystroke not autorise

Tags: applescript

I have problem with the keystrokes when I use the system events in applescript application. Indeed, when I run the applescript program with keystrokes in system events, the message : The name of the program is not allowed to send key entries Appears. I can't fixed this problm.

Comment: Go to _System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility_ and add your script. Make sure that your script doesn’t have spaces or hyphens in its name. Additionally you can add the AppleScript Editor (or Automator).

Comment: slartibatfast. I did your idea "Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility and add your script" all and also Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Automatic and add your script. And noting done. I'm feed-up.

Comment: you have to grant full disk access - it’s a quite common error, [see this thread with screenshots on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973241/applescript-application-is-not-allowed-to-send-keystrokes).